# Does the iPhone 6 "CPU-throttling" feature stop after the battery is replaced?

Tags: ios, performance, power-management

There is recent news (acknowledged by Apple) of a feature in some software versions of iOS that reduces the current usage of the iPhone6 and 6S when the battery ages and is less able to supply current, and this makes sense. It tries to prevent the phone from suddenly shutting down when the battery can not supply the required current.

I've suffered from those shut-downs first hand by trying to [get the last few weeks out of a clearly-dead battery](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/167812/115702) - which is unadvisable to say the least!

Is it known *for a fact* if this feature reinstates the phone to original performance and speed after the battery is replaced?

Comment: I have made similar observations to the other answers here, in that my iPhone 6 is still being throttled after replacing the battery with a 3rd party part. Geekbench scores are roughly 1/2 of the ideal score. "Battery analyze" apps report a perfect battery in terms of max. capacity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the CPU throttling will stop once device's battery is replaced.
In a statment to [TechCrunch](https://techcrunch.com/2017/12/20/apple-addresses-why-people-are-saying-their-iphones-with-older-batteries-are-running-slower/), Apple says they will throttle devices "only when needed."

> Last year we released a feature for iPhone 6, iPhone 6s and iPhone SE to smooth out the instantaneous peaks only when needed to prevent the device from unexpectedly shutting down during these conditions.

As this happens "only when needed," replacing the battery should stop CPU throttling from happening. Explaining his experience with the same issue, Forbes contributor [Antony Leather](https://www.forbes.com/sites/antonyleather/#3c1ef43d64f6) says that performance did increase on his iPhone 6 after replacing the battery.

> My iPhone 6 was a prime candidate - I had actually replaced the
>   battery myself a couple of years ago, but I'm a heavy user and already
>   noticed its longevity had started to decrease again...
>
> Finally, I replaced the battery with a new one from Amazon, charged it
>   to be well away from the low power mode level and re-ran the test. The
>   difference was incredible. The single core score rose from 1038 to
>   1562 - an increase of precisely 50%.

Check out Forbes' *[Boost Your iPhone Speed By 50%: How To Replace The Battery And Stop Apple Degrading Performance](https://www.forbes.com/sites/antonyleather/2017/12/22/boost-your-iphone-speed-by-50-how-to-replace-the-battery-and-stop-apple-degrading-performance/#293be58656fb)*

Check out this excerpt from How-To Geek's *[You can Speed Up You Slow iPhone by Replacing the Battery](https://www.howtogeek.com/337005/you-can-speed-up-your-slow-iphone-by-replacing-the-battery/)*, which suggests that replacing the battery will improve performance.

> If your phone is indeed slowing down as a result of poor battery health, replacing the battery will give your phone new life. Not only will you get a longer-lasting battery by replacing an old one, but your phone should jump back up to its top speed.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the nicely-sourced answer!

Comment: Of course! Good luck servicing your iPhone!

Answer (score -1):

Not really. Mine went down to 600 - 911 MHz after just 18 charging cycles.

Answer (score -3):

I replaced my battery on iPhone 6 and it's still throttled the same as the previous battery. At 100% charge it's only 1127 MHz vs spec of 1400Mhz. At lower charges it decreases to 600 MHz.

All battery indicators (coconut, and multiple battery apps) say that voltage is at 4.2V (at full charge) and capacity is at 1810 mAh, so technically a perfect battery. Note that it's a 3rd party battery not an apple one.

I wonder if they're punishing users for not using OEM batteries. All tech indicators say that the battery is in good health and throttling should not be happening.

Answer (score -4):

I replaced the battery on my iPhone 6s and the cpu is still throttled at 600 MHz.  Run a cpu MHz year after swap and you will see the truth that it’s the software update that is the issue.

Answer (score -4):

Not sure why someone is downvoting these alternate observations, but I have similar experience.

I just replaced my son's iPhone 6 battery with a new third party one that seems technically ok (coconut and a few battery apps I tried claim full capacity, voltage and no prior charge cycles). Still the CPU is throttled to 839 MHz at full charge and 600 MHz at lower charges.

EDIT: tried a DFU restore too, didn't help